# Reduce() is not working as expected in Kotlin for sum operation for some value

Tags: arrays, kotlin, split, reduce

```
val arr = arrayListOf(256741038, 623958417 ,467905213, 714532089, 938071625)
arr.sort()
val max = (arr.slice(1 until arr.size)).reduce { x, ars  -> x+ars }
```

so I want the max sum of 4 out of 5 elements in an array but I am having an answer which is not expected

> max = -1550499952

I don't know what going wrong there because it's working for many cases but not for this.

The expected output would be:

> max = 2744467344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever see a negative number appearing out of nowhere, that's a sign that you've got an overflow. The largest number an `Int` can represent is [*2147483647*](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt#L518) - add *1* to that and you get *-2147483648*, a **negative** number.

That's because signed integers represent negative numbers with a *1* in the most significant bit of the binary representation. Your largest *positive* number is `0111` (except with *32* bits not *4*!), then you add *1* and it ticks over to `1000`, the largest *negative* number. Then as you add to that, it moves towards zero, until you have `1111` (which is *-1*). Add another *1* and it overflows (there's no space to represent `10000`) and you're back at zero, `0000`.

---

Anyway point is you're adding lots of big numbers together and an `Int` can't hold the result. It keeps overflowing, so you lose the bigger digits (it can't represent more than ~2 billion) and it can be negative depending on where the overflow ends up, which half of the binary range it lands in.

You can fix this by using `Long`s instead (*64-bits*, max values +/- 9 quintillion, lots of room):

```
// note the L's to make them Longs
arrayListOf(256741038L, 623958417L ,467905213L, 714532089L, 938071625L)
```